# Excel - sum nested levels

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

example file: https://app.box.com/shared/static/iqfjj51hmusu6uk0exwjfnwkjdlwhezr.xlsx

I have some products which are made of many components.
In the example above my main product is made of n 5 Level 2 components, some of these Level 2 components are in turn made of many Level 3 components and so on.

Each one of them has a fixed price (column B).

Now, the question: I need to calculate the total for each level +  it's sub levels. In the example this is done manually, so let's take C3, you can see it's the sum of Level 2 itself + all the Level 3 components I need in order to manufacture it. Same goes for C8: the corresponding Level 3 component is made of n2 Level 4 components. Hope the example is clear enough.

This is quite easy when done manually however I need a formula in column C which would select the correct cells for me (based on the value column A) since the range would be dynamic, meaning I can have has many sub-levels as I want and the number of rows is never fixed: right now level 3 goes A4:A8 but it could easily be A4:A6, A7:A30, you get the gist.

I'm really stuck, I don't know how to do this in VBA and I've tried a few formulas (offset + if, match, index...) to see if I can come up with something but no luck.

Does anybody have a suggestion/link or, even better, a solution?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm sure the levels are not called 1, 2, 3, 4. Can you use an example with a level hierarchy naming that more closely resembles the real thing? Is level 2 always the same text? Also, put in some sample data with more than one level 1 field.

Comment: Thanks @teylyn. This is a stripped down example but levels (column A) are always called 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 or 8. It's a real thing example, it has just one Level 1 (it is used as a placeholder).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this kind of VBA user-defined cell formula?
Use cell formula `=sumSubLevels(A2)` in C2 cell, `=sumSubLevels(A3)` in C3 cell and so on. This example adds a current level+all recursive sublevels. This is a simple BOM(bill-of-material) case.

```
Option Explicit

Public Function sumSubLevels(rSource As Range) As Double
    Dim iLevel As Long, iSubLevel As Long, iRow As Long
    Dim dSum As Double

    iLevel = rSource.Value
    iRow = 0
    dSum = rSource.Offset(0, 1)
    Do While (True)
        iRow = iRow + 1
        If rSource.Offset(iRow, 0) = "" Then Exit Do
        iSubLevel = rSource.Offset(iRow, 0)
        If iSubLevel > iLevel Then
            dSum = dSum + rSource.Offset(iRow, 1)
        ElseIf iSubLevel <= iLevel Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
    sumSubLevels = dSum
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you @Whome! Almost. I need the current level + the next immediate sublevel only. C3 should be: current level (B3) + the next immediate sub level (B4:B8); C11= current level (B11)+next sublevel (B12:B13);C8=current level(B8)+next sublevel(B9:B10) and so on.

Comment: @Barbara This `If iSubLevel=iLevel+1 Then` condition should do the trick?

Comment: YES! This is exactly what I was looking for. I have only a basic grasp of VBA so I'm going to study your code and try to figure it all out. Thank you @Whome for taking the time to help me. :D

Comment: @Barbara If you want to parameterize `level,price` column index you may introduce two new func arguments `sumSubLevels(rSource As Range, levelCol as Integer, priceCol as Integer)` then no need to hardcode in VBA side. I leave this to your home work.

Comment: Will do. Thanks.